# GKComponentSystem has no components on update cycle

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I’m playing around with SpriteKit and GameplayKit. But when I run my code, the sprite I’m expecting to wander around, does nothing.

I used lldb to print out some values, this is the print out:

```
(lldb) po agentSystem.components
▿ 1 elements
  - [0] : <GKAgent2D: 0x7fc1b8e55ff0>

(lldb) po agentSystem.components
0 elements
```

The first is printed just after `addComponentWithEntity:` is called.
The second is printed in the `update:` method.

Of course this must be the reason the sprite does not wander, but what could be causing the problem?

I’ve even looked at and used code from Apple’s [sample code for Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AgentsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) but that still doesn’t seem to fix the issue.

Here is my scene’s code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene
{
    //  MARK: - Properties

    let agentSystem = GKComponentSystem(componentClass: GKAgent2D.self)

    var lastUpdateTimeInterval: CFTimeInterval = 0.0


    //  MARK: - Scene Lifecycle

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
        //  Wave enemy
        let agent = GKAgent2D()
        agent.behavior = GKBehavior(goal: GKGoal(toWander: 10), weight: 100)

        let waveEnemy = WaveEnemy()
        waveEnemy.addComponent(agent)

        agentSystem.addComponentWithEntity(waveEnemy)

        let waveSprite = waveEnemy.componentForClass(VisualComponent)!.spriteNode
        waveSprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * 0.5, y: frame.size.height * 0.5)

        addChild(waveSprite)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
    {
        if lastUpdateTimeInterval == 0
        {
            lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime
        }

        let deltaTime: CFTimeInterval = currentTime - lastUpdateTimeInterval
        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime

        //  Update component system
        agentSystem.updateWithDeltaTime(deltaTime)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Turns out my GKEntity had a weak reference to it which caused it to automatically get removed from the GKComponentSystem.

In your case you're creating `waveEnemy` which needs to be held on to. You can store it in an array on the scene.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    ...

    var enemies = [GKEntity]()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        ...
        let waveEnemy = WaveEnemy()
        waveEnemy.addComponent(agent)
        enemies.append(waveEnemy) // Creates a strong reference for waveEnemy
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Yeah this was the fix for me too if I remember correctly - forgot to update the question! Thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! PS. Is there a way to debug weak/strong references?

Comment: Oh my goodness I've been searching for hours! This totally fixed my game! Thank you very much. Just adding the var enemies = [GKEntity]() line and appending the new entity to create a strong reference was the only thing I was missing. Thank you!